# How to extract href links from anchor tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract just the links corresponding to the jobs on each page. But for some reason they dont print when I execute the script. No errors occur.
for the inputs I put engineering, toronto respectively. Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

jobsearch = input("What type of job?: ")
location = input("What is your location: ")
url = ("https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=" + jobsearch + "&l=" + location)

r = requests.get(url)
rcontent = r.content
prettify = BeautifulSoup(rcontent, "html.parser")

all_job_url = []

for tag in prettify.find_all('div', {'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"}):
    for links in tag.find_all('a'):
        print (links['href'])
```

Comment: I have a feeling you need to use `attrs` like `for tag in prettify.find_all('div', attrs={'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"})`

Comment: @jamesSchinner I tried that it didnt work

Comment: Looks like COLDSPEED has a pretty good answer. but worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be looking for the anchor `a` tag. It looks like this:

```
<a class="turnstileLink" data-tn-element="jobTitle" href="/rc/clk?jk=3611ac98c0167102&amp;fccid=459dce363200e1be" ...>Project <b>Engineer</b></a>
```

Call `soup.find_all` and iterate over the result set, extracting the links through the `href` attribute.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# valid query, replace with something else
url = "https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=engineer&l=Calgary%2C+AB" 

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

all_job_url = []    
for tag in soup.find_all('a', {'data-tn-element':"jobTitle"}):
    all_job_url.append(tag['href'])
```